# Site looks responsive in developer tools when switched to mobile view but looks bad on actual smartphone

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design

As the title says, my website looks very bad on actual smartphones (tried Samsung s5 and OnePlus One). The desktop version of my site is displayed (miniaturized of course) very much the same on smartphones. Although when I switch to developer tools and check the mobile mode, it looks very much like I want it.

Here are some images:

[image: View from OnePLus One Smartphone]

[image: Desktop view]

[image: Dev Tools View]

I don't think it is a good idea to put all the CSS here cause it's huge.

What are the areas that might be troubelsome in my situation? Where should I look? What are the "responsive" elements I must have in my CSS for this to work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you added a viewport meta tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Are you using any Media Queries to adjust the size of different elements on your page depending on the screen resolution? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I'll check it soon and come back to you with more details. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.